# Concatenate pyspark Columns into a pyspark DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am working with python and currently have a couple of instances of class `pyspark.sql.column.Column` and would like to concatenate them such that I get a  `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` object with the mentioned columns. Let me illustrate this with the following toy example.

**Toy Example**

1) Let us first create a sample pyspark DataFrame so as to be able to get two example columns.

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
# Create a DataFrame
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("Jordi", 14, 45), ("Elisabeth", 22, 63), ("Aina", 8, 35)], ("name", "age", "weight"))
# Get two columns
col1 = df.name
col2 = df.age
```

2) Now my goal is to be able to combine variables `col1` and `col2` into a single DataFrame, such that this new DataFrame contains two columns:

```
|   name    |   age  |
|-----------+--------|
| Jordi     |   14   |
| Elisabeth |   22   |
| Aina      |   8    |
```

Comment: what do you mean by merge? you want to union or join them? an expected dataframe and input dataframe should clarify what you are intending

Comment: Thanks Ramesh. By merge I meant to create a DataFrame with two columns.

Comment: you probably are looking for join but you would need a condition for join. can you just clarify with samples ?

Comment: I have two columns, both of same length (say n). I want to create a DataFrame with n rows and 2 columns. I have updated the comment with an example of how the new created DataFrame should look like.

Comment: I commented above also that you would need a condition. for example how do you tell spark to join Jordi with 14 and not with 22 or 8 and the same case with Elisabeth and Aina? are you getting my point

Comment: I see, I get you. Thought it was simpler but I guess that the distributed nature of spark makes it a bit more complex. So not sure how to define such condition.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to create dataframe from spark columns which are used for experessions. You can use select statement for this:

```
df.select('name', 'age')
```

If you have 2 dataframes and no way to join them by common column:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

df_temp1 = df1 \
             .select(col1) \
             .rdd \
             .zipWithIndex() # (row, id) \
             .map(lambda row: Row(id=row[1], **row[0].asDict())) \
             .toDf()

df_temp2 = df2 \
             .select(col2) \
             .rdd \
             .zipWithIndex() # (row, id) \
             .map(lambda row: Row(id=row[1], **row[0].asDict())) \
             .toDf()
 df = df2_temp.join(df1_temp, 'id')
```

Comment: I am trying to find a general solution for the case that you have two columns and would like to create a DataFrame from them. So actually the variable `df` shouldn't be used. Imagine these columns come from two different DataFrames...

Comment: There is no way to combine 2 dataframes with columns. But you can add index to columns and then join them.